# Add Custom Post type menu to another menu in specific location

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-development, admin-menu

It is possible to add the menu for a custom post type beneath another menu (in my case a custom one that I have created) but this appears as the first item.

How exactly do I move this to a different position - say 2nd or 3rd in the list?

Wordpress advises:

> Note: When using 'some string' to show as a submenu of a menu page
>   created by a plugin, this item will become the first submenu item, and
>   replace the location of the top-level link. If this isn't desired, the
>   plugin that creates the menu page needs to set the add_action priority
>   for admin_menu to 9 or lower.

However how exactly do I apply this?

I'm a bit stuck for an answer on this one. The function add_menu_page() allows a numerical position argument but this is for the top level position. The function add_submenu_page() doesnt seem to allow a position to be set.

TIA

Comment: in the hook "admin_menu", you can read `$GLOBALS["wp_menu"]` and `$GLOBALS["wp_submenu"]` and reorder them

Comment: Thanks @mmm much appreciated, just one follow-up -  here you list the variables as prefixed with "wp_", my $GLOBALS array omits these, just using keys as "menu" and "submenu". Does this mean there is some variability that one needs to account for? And as such is there a convenient way to check? (and then we dive down the rabbit warren!)

Comment: yes you are right, the good arrays are `$GLOBALS["menu"]` and `$GLOBALS["submenu"]`

Answer (score 0):

Fixed and here's how, please excuse the unedited cut and paste, thanks to @mmm for the pointers on how:

1. Add Custom Post Type via Action

   add_action('init', array($this, 'mactrak_custom_post_type_add'));
2. Above function as called (mactrak_custom_post_type_add) includes argument to set up meta box and menu position
3. Following construct:

   add_action('admin_menu', array(&$this,'mactrak_admin_menu'));
4. runs following script:

   add_menu_page( 'MacTrak - the WP FindMeSpot Interface', 'MacTrak', 'edit_posts', 'wp_mactrak_admin_menu', array($this,'mactrak_admin_main'),'dashicons-location-alt', 30);

   $customMarkerTemp = array_pop($GLOBALS['submenu']['wp_mactrak_admin_menu']); // Remove Custom Marker Item from Sub menu

   add_submenu_page( 'wp_mactrak_admin_menu', 'MacTrak - the WP FindMeSpot Interface', 'My Tracker Map', 'edit_posts', 'wp_mactrak_admin_menu', array($this,'mactrak_admin_main'));
   add_submenu_page( 'wp_mactrak_admin_menu', 'MacTrak - FindMeSpot Data', 'FindMeSpot Data', 'edit_posts', 'wp_mactrak_admin_fmsdata', array($this,'mactrak_admin_fmsdata'));
   add_submenu_page( 'wp_mactrak_admin_menu', 'MacTrak - Custom Flight Lines', 'Custom Flight Lines', 'edit_posts', 'wp_mactrak_admin_customlines', array($this,'mactrak_admin_customlines'));
       $GLOBALS['submenu']['wp_mactrak_admin_menu'][] = $customMarkerTemp; // Reinsert Custom Markers item in order
   add_submenu_page( 'wp_mactrak_admin_menu', 'MacTrak - Current Location', 'Current Location', 'edit_posts', 'wp_mactrak_admin_currentloc', array($this,'mactrak_admin_currentloc'));
   add_submenu_page( 'wp_mactrak_admin_menu', 'MacTrak - Settings', 'Settings', 'edit_pages', 'wp_mactrak_admin_settings', array($this,'mactrak_admin_settings'));